# zombiejs integration with java application

Tags: java, seo, web-crawler, phantomjs, zombie.js

Following previous post regarding crawling issues (#!) with a single page application we decided to get rid of html unit ( which is very slow for JS [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715598/crawler-for-gwt-application-taking-too-much-time)) and choosed to implement Phantom Js whith pushstate (to get pretty urls). 
Due to Phantom Js non support of pushstate, we are now considering implementing Zombie Js (hopefully the last change!).

Any tips to implement zombie for Java app? 
or any other headless browser (which supports pushstate and have a powerfull Js engine)that would fit better?

Answer (score 0):

pushstate doesn't work because of the actual embedded version of webkit doesn't support pushstate. it'll be included for the coming 2.x series version (I hope for the next 2.0) of phantomjs.

by the way, I didn't understand your question :

> Any tips to implement zombie for Java app?

do you mean re-implement zombiejs with java ?

I just checked out and I found that casperJS (based on phantomJS) handles correctly pushState. You should actually give it a try as I know the developer I think he'll be very excited to have feedback about the pushState feature.

Hope it'll help you !